# Userscript for chromium/Bromtie on Android for playing Youtube Music continuesly

Tags: javascript, chromium, userscripts

I am using youtube music in my webbrowser on Android for blocking ads this way. I have a userscript installed in bromite for this job. As a side effect, the music stops playing after each song, even without blocking the ads. I tried a script for it which worked in bromite but not working in a different fork of chromium which I chose above bromite after it seems like its discontinued now.

But I just dont know why it does not get triggered anymore, maybe you can help out.
The code I used so far working in bromite:

```
let lastUrl = location.href; 
new MutationObserver(() => {
  const url = location.href;
  if (url !== lastUrl) {
    lastUrl = url;
    onUrlChange();
  }
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function onUrlChange() {

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("play-pause-button").click();
  }, 1000);

}
```

I already tried the code above and expect that when the url changes (moving to the next song) the playbutton gets triggered so the music keeps playing.

Comment: In case you're using Tampermonkey, you might be interested in [`window.close`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:window.close).